# Finding Generating Member of Group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups

Consider the following 2 subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{1260}$:

$$H_1=\langle 155\rangle,   H_2 = \langle 261\rangle $$

My book claims that $135$ is the generator for $H_1 \cap H_2$

How can I discover that?

The $\gcd$ of $155$ and $261$ is $1$ and not $135$ ... every number is a multiple of $155$ and $261$ iff it is a multiple of their ${\rm lcm}$

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Divisibility reverses inclusion in subgroups of the integers. If $a$ divides $b$, then $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a\rangle$. You want the lcm, not the gcd.

Comment: In fact $H_1 = \langle 5 \rangle$, $H_2 = \langle 9 \rangle$, $H_1 \cap H_2 = \langle 45 \rangle$, but $135$ is also a generator of $H_1 \cap H_2$.

Comment: Incidentally, if you are quoting your book correctly, then it is inaccurate. $135$ is *a* generator of $H_1 \cap H_2$, not *the* generator.